# How to update map or list type json to Dynamodb using batch-write-itme commend?

Tags: json, amazon-dynamodb

I'm trying to update bulk data to dynamodb using batch-write-item commend with map or list type json file but I got error.

1. This is a map type json

```
{
  "TestDB":[
  {
    "PutRequest":{
      "Item":{
          "Name":{"S": "UserName"},
          "ToolOne":{
                "item":{"S": "excel"},
                "qty":{"N": "2"},
                "desc":{"S": "eeee"}
             },
           "ToolTwo":{
                 "item":{"S": "Word"},
                 "qty":{"N": "1"},
                 "desc":{"S": "www"}
            }
        }
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

and this is error message

```
Parameter validation failed:
Unknown parameter in RequestItems.TestDB[0].PutRequest.Item.ToolOne: "item", must be one of: S, N, B, SS, NS, BS, M, L, NULL, BOOL
Unknown parameter in RequestItems.TestDB[0].PutRequest.Item.ToolOne: "qty", must be one of: S, N, B, SS, NS, BS, M, L, NULL, BOOL
Unknown parameter in RequestItems.TestDB[0].PutRequest.Item.ToolOne: "desc", must be one of: S, N, B, SS, NS, BS, M, L, NULL, BOOL
Unknown parameter in RequestItems.TestDB[0].PutRequest.Item.ToolTwo: "item", must be one of: S, N, B, SS, NS, BS, M, L, NULL, BOOL
Unknown parameter in RequestItems.TestDB[0].PutRequest.Item.ToolTwo: "qty", must be one of: S, N, B, SS, NS, BS, M, L, NULL, BOOL
Unknown parameter in RequestItems.TestDB[0].PutRequest.Item.ToolTwo: "desc", must be one of: S, N, B, SS, NS, BS, M, L, NULL, BOOL
```

2. This is a list type json

```
{
  "TestDB":[
  {
    "PutRequest":{
      "Item":{
          "Name":{"S": "userName"},
          "ToolOne":[
                {"S": "excel"},
                {"N": "2"},
                {"S": "eeee"}
             ],
           "ToolTwo":[
                 {"S": "Word"},
                 {"N": "1"},
                 {"S": "www"}
            ]
        }
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

and this is an error message

```
Invalid type for parameter RequestItems.TestDB[0].PutRequest.Item.ToolOne, value: [OrderedDict([('S', 'excel')]), OrderedDict([('N', '2')]), OrderedDict([('S', 'eeee')])], type: <class 'list'>, valid types: <class 'dict'>
Invalid type for parameter RequestItems.TestDB[0].PutRequest.Item.ToolTwo, value: [OrderedDict([('S', 'Word')]), OrderedDict([('N', '1')]), OrderedDict([('S', 'www')])], type: <class 'list'>, valid types: <class 'dict'>
```

Below aws cli commend is what I used to update.

```
aws dynamodb batch-write-item --request-items file://Json_file_name.json
```

Could you help me out what is wrong in my json?

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution. I can find ways of expression(below link) for nested json
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/APIReference/API_AttributeValue.html

Comment: Please provide additional details in your answer. As it's currently written, it's hard to understand your solution.